# Why strcmp tell me a variable is an integer when it's not

Tags: c

I have a compilation error, after hours of researching I came across that is trying to tell me that my `var"` is type integer, but in my code I set the output as a string. I dont understand where's the problem I just want a program that collects how many times a word is in a sentence.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int j = 0;

int cadena(char ciudad[50], char letra[2]) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(ciudad); i++)
        if (strcmp(ciudad[i], letra) == 0);
            j += 1;

    return j;
}

int main() {
    char ciudad_1[50];
    char letra_1[2];

    printf("Dame tu ciudad: ");
    gets(ciudad_1);
    printf("Dame la letra la cual quieres contar: ");
    scanf("%s", letra_1);

    printf("Esta son las veces que se repite tu letra %d", cadena(ciudad_1, letra_1));
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see `gets(ciudad_1);` `char ciudad_1[50]` is set as string why I getting these errors.

The compilations error are the following:

```
pag_113.c: In function 'cadena':
pag_113.c:11:3: warning: passing argument 1 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
In file included from pag_113.c:2:0:
c:\pentestbox\base\ruby_devkit\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/include/string.h:53:15: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'char'
```

Thank you for your time guys, I really hope I can solve this newbie question.

Comment: `ciudad[i]` is a `char`, not a string. `char` is an integer type.

Comment: **C does not have strings.** C only has arrays of `char`.  A `char` is a small integer.

Comment: The `char` type is an 8-bit integer, often used for ASCII characters. `strcmp()` and similar functions take *pointers* to them.

Comment: `if (strcmp(ciudad[i], letra) == 0);` --> `if (strncmp(&ciudad[i], letra, 1) == 0)` or `if (ciudad[i] == letra[0])`

Comment: @GlennTinoco: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 2):

`strcmp` expects it's both arguments of type `char *` while `ciudad[i]` is of type `char`.

Comment: Thanks now the program is executing fine.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems in your `cadena` function:

- `strcmp()` is used to compare C strings, in your function, you want to compare individual characters.  You can do it with the `==` operator on the array elements.
- You should make the counter variable local to the function, not global.
- the `if` statement `if (strcmp(ciudad[i], letra) == 0);` has a spurious `;` at the end of the line: this is an empty statement.  The `j += 1;` statement would be executed unconditionally.

Here is a corrected version:

```
int cadena(char ciudad[50], char letra[2]) {
    int i;
    int count = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(ciudad); i++)
        if (ciudad[i] == letra[0])
            count += 1;

    return count;
}
```

Note also that you should not use `gets()`. This function has been removed from the latest C Standard library because it cannot be used safely as the size of the destination array cannot be passed to the function, so sufficiently long input with definitely cause a buffer overflow.  Use `fgets()` or `scanf()` instead.

Here is a simpler version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int cadena(const char *ciudad, char letra) {
    int i;
    int count = 0;

    for (i = 0; ciudad[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (ciudad[i] == letra)
            count += 1;
    }
    return count;
}

int main(void) {
    char ciudad_1[50];
    char letra_1;

    printf("Dame tu ciudad: ");
    if (scanf("%49[^\n]", ciudad_1) != 1)
        return 1;
    printf("Dame la letra la cual quieres contar: ");
    if (scanf(" %c", &letra_1) != 1)
        return 1;

    printf("Esta son las veces que se repite tu letra: %d\n",
           cadena(ciudad_1, letra_1));
    return 0;
}
```